# Makefile: how to set up prerequisites for two lists of files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have two lists of files as prerequisites

- `input_i.xx`
- `config_j.yy`

and I need to run all of their combinations. A single one looks like this:

```
input1_config3.output: input1.xx config3.yy
    run_script $^
```

Also in reality, their names are not numbered, but I already have their stems defined in `INPUTS` and `CONFIGS`. With that, I can generate all the targets together

```
TARGETS:=$(foreach input,$(INPUTS),$(foreach config,$(CONFIGS),$(input)_$(config).output))
```

But I have difficulty with the prerequisites. It seems I need to

1. get basename
2. split on `_`
3. add the extensions `.xx` and `.yy`

```
.SECONDEXPANSION
$(TARGETS): $(basename $@)
    run_script $^
```

Can someone show me how to do that? Not sure if this the proper way, maybe a bottom-up way is easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a lot easier if you provided a complete sample example with a complete set of targets and prerequisites and exactly what you wanted to happen.

Using `.SECONDEXPANSION` *might* work, but you're not using it correctly; please re-read the documentation.  The critical aspect of `.SECONDEXPANSION` is that you have to *escape* the variables that you want to avoid expanding until the second pass.  In your example you've not escaped anything, so `.SECONDEXPANSION` isn't actually doing anything at all here.  However, as @tripleee points out it's not easy to use multiple variable values in a single target.

To do this more easily you'll probably want to use `eval`.  Something like this:

```
define DECLARE
$1_$2.output: $1.xx $2.yy
TARGETS += $1_$2.output
endef

TARGETS :=
$(foreach input,$(INPUTS),$(foreach config,$(CONFIGS),$(eval $(call DECLARE,$(input),$(config)))))

$(TARGETS):
        run_script $^
```

Comment: thanks, I just realized another solution: `include` another makefile that doesn't exist yet, and use bash loop to write out its content as a target

Comment: Yes, that will work too.  The only issue there is ensuring that the included file is marked obsolete and rebuilt if/when you change the content of the `INPUTS` or `CONFIGS` variables.

Answer (score 1):

`make` is not really suitable for keeping track of an M x N matrix of results. The fundamental problem is that you can't have two stems in a rule, so you can't say something like

```
# BROKEN
input%{X}_config%{Y}.output: input%{X}.xx config%{Y}.yy
```

As a rough approximation, you could use a recursive `make` rule to set a couple of parameters, and take it from there, but this is rather clumsy.

```
.PHONY: all
all:
    $(MAKE) -$(MAKEFLAGS) X=1 Y=6 input1_config6.output
    $(MAKE) -$(MAKEFLAGS) X=1 Y=7 input1_config7.output
    $(MAKE) -$(MAKEFLAGS) X=2 Y=6 input2_config6.output
    :
    
input$X_config$Y.output: input$X.xx config$Y.yy
    run_script $^
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution using `include` and bash `for` loop.

```
include trees.mk

trees.mk:
    @for input in $(INPUTS); do \
        for config in $(CONFIGS); do \
            echo $${input}_$$config.output : $${input}.xx $$config.yy; \
            echo -e '\t run_scipt $$^ ';\
        done \
    done > $@
```

At the beginning, `trees.mk` doesn't exist. The double `for` loops write out the rule to the target using file redirection `>$@`.

I got this idea from [Managing Projects with GNU Make, Third Edition By Robert Mecklenburg](https://www.oreilly.com/openbook/make3/book/), on
[page 56](https://www.oreilly.com/openbook/make3/book/ch03.pdf)